# Multi Column Listbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm needed to create a list box as in below format;

```
[x]    [x]   ^
[x]    [x]   |
[x]    [x]   | ----> this is a side scroll and the [x] are pictures
[x]    [x]   |
```

How can I do it? Here is my code now.

```
      <controls:PanoramaItem Header="New one"  Name="Pan1" >
                <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" x:Name="NewTitlesListBox" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding NewPicturesLocal}" 
                         SelectionChanged="NewListBoxSelectionChanged">

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
   <Image  Width="110" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Source="{Binding ThumbURL}" 
                                    Margin="12,0,9,0"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

The result of this:

```
[x]   ^
[x]   |
[x]   | ----> this is a side scroll and the [x] are pictures
[x]   |
```

I was trying to do it with Grid (adding more columns) and with Data Templating, but didn’t find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be to use the WrapPanel from the Silverlight Toolkit:
[WrapPanel for WP7](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth). You would have to set the ItemsPanelTemplate for your ListBox to use the WrapPanel. There's an example of that in the comments of the page I linked to.

Answer (score 4):

Using the WrapPanel from the Silverlight Toolkit will be solution to my question

```
      <controls:PanoramaItem Header="New one"  Name="Pan1" >
                <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" x:Name="NewTitlesListBox" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding NewPicturesLocal}" 
                         SelectionChanged="NewListBoxSelectionChanged">

                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
   <Image  Width="110" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Source="{Binding ThumbURL}" 
                                    Margin="12,0,9,0"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Comment: Glad you posted your solution. I'm sure this will be handy for somebody else.